# Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I have created a docker 16.4 container and trying to run a docker within the container. Following this article.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

I followed everything but when I start the container I get the following issues.

```
root@1c2464056cff:/# sudo systemctl status docker
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
docker run -ti -d --privileged=true images_docker  "/sbin/init"
```

or

```
docker run -ti -d --privileged=true images_docker
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work even if you change the entrypoint to "/sbin/init"